# Auth::attempt return true, Auth::check() return false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent, laravel-9

I'm using Laravel 9 authentication. It's a successful login, but on the main page, it is not logged in. So I'm expecting it to authenticate.

**Login controller**

```
if (Auth::attempt([
    'x_username' => $data['username'],
    'x_user_password' => $data['password']
])) {
    return true; //login success
} else {
    return false;
}
```

**Dashboard controller (it shows 2)**

```
if(Auth::check()) {
    echo "1"; //not happened, but login before is success?
} else {
    echo "2"; 
}

$user = Auth::user();
var_dump($user); //it shows NULL
```

**Models**

```
// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'tbl_x_user';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'x_username',
        'x_user_email',
        'x_user_password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'x_user_password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->x_user_password;
    }
}
```

**auth.php**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
],
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
'password_timeout' => 10800,
```

**kernels.php**

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

**Notes**

- changing the primary key and primary key name with and without disable increment is not working
- the session in /storage/framework/sessions/ is created
- session.php is not edited (defaults laravel)
- my password field using varchar(255)

Comment: If you change the primary key name you need to add `$primaryKey` poperty in your model like [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys)

Comment: i'm already do that and still have same problem

Comment: Can you do an `Auth::user()`?

Comment: $user = Auth::user();
        var_dump($user);

it shows NULL;

Comment: I think there is some problem inside routes files with middleware group. Please share your routes file.

Comment: does `attempt` return true when user/password is invalid

Comment: you don't seem to be using the default auth system that comes with Laravel ... the password field used for the credentials passed to `attempt` **MUST** be named `password`; which does not relate to the actual name of the password field on the table as this field is left out of the query since the password is hashed and a hash check needs to be performed ... so it seems you are leaving out details here

Comment: Is your route has `auth` middleware? because you must have to attach `auth` middleware with your desired route.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In Blade:

```
@auth
    // User is Authenticated
@else
    // User is Not Authenticated
@endauth
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the middleware to the route?

```
Route::get('/', function () {})->middleware('auth');
```

or you can do this inside the controller

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a couple of hours found a solution for this. The issue cause is

> `auth()->attempt` always check fields such as `username`, `email`, `password`. In your case, you have used a custom column name on the table.

The solution that I found is

1. Installed two new libraries via composer. (`Mappable`)
2. Mapped your custom table fields to standard nameing fields.

**Bonus**

> Now, you can use `username` to get the field data. Ex:

```
$user = User::where(['username' => 'ab'])->first();
$user->username(); # bonus
```

---

### Install [Mappable](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence-mappablehttps://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence-mappable) and [Eloquence](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence)

```
composer require sofa/eloquence 
composer require sofa/eloquence-mappable
```

---

### **In the `User` model**

**Import**

```
use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Mappable;
```

**use**

```
use Eloquence, Mappable;
```

**In model body**

```
protected array $maps = [
    'username' => 'x_username', # I used x_username as my local test 
    'password' => 'x_user_password',
];
```

---

### In Controller

```
if (auth()->attempt(['username' => 'ab', 'password' => 'ab@123'])) {
    return view('welcome');
} else {
    return "not logged in";
}
```

> **IMPORTANT: Laravel encrypts passwords using [Hashing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing). So make sure your password is hashed in the DB. Because Auth `attempt()` always works with *Hashing***

---

For testing purposes, I used `welcome.blade.php.`

```
@auth
    <h3>Logged In</h3>
@else
    <h3>Not yet Logged In</h3>
@endauth
```

And the output was

[image]

---

## Test data

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('x_users', static function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('x_username');
    $table->string('x_user_email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('x_user_password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**User create**

```
User::create([
    'x_username' => 'ab',
    'x_user_email' => 'ab@abc.com',
    'x_user_password' => Hash::make('ab@123'),
]);
```

**In model**

Used `$guarded` to ignore [`MassAssignment` error](https://dev.to/zubairmohsin33/understanding-mass-assignment-in-laravel-eloquent-orm-331g) (Not recommended. Just for time save)

```
protected $table = 'x_users';
protected $guarded = [];
```

Comment: did you check this ?

Answer (score 0):

### Set up

I've tested it on a new Laravel app with simple [Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze) authentication, see below for the set-up used.

```bash
$ laravel new testing
$ cd testing
$ composer require laravel/breeze --dev
$ php artisan breeze:install
```

Then I've updated the users migration like this:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('x_username')->unique();
    $table->string('x_user_email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('x_user_password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then I've run `php artisan migrate:fresh`, which will rebuild the database from scratch.

Inside the `RegisteredUserController` I've made an update to use the new fields you specified:

```php
$user = User::create([
    'x_username' => $request->name,
    'x_user_email' => $request->email,
    'x_user_password' => Hash::make($request->password),
]);
```

I've updated the model according to what you set in your question.

Then I've registered a new user through visiting `/register`.

I'm automatically logged in after registering, so I'll logout using the logout link provided in the navigation from Breeze.

Now, inside `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php` I've changed the email address field to use the username:

```html
<div>
    <x-input-label for="username" value="Username" />

    <x-text-input id="username" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="username" :value="old('username')" required autofocus />

    <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('username')" class="mt-2" />
</div>
```

#### Actually getting to the login problem.

So now that the project is set up, let's have a look at what isn't working. To log in with the new fields we'll need to change the login code (in Breeze's case the `App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest`.

I've changed the `authenticate` method inside the request as follows:

```php
public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (! Auth::attempt([
        'x_username' => $this->input('username'),
        'password' => $this->input('password'),
    ], $this->boolean('remember'))) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => trans('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

Note that credentials should contain two types of fields:

1. One or more fields that are unencrypted, and can thus be used to fetch the possible user from the database.
2. The password field (which is encrypted).

In the example code the field that's used to fetch the user from the database is `x_username` (Laravel filters out all fields containing the key `password`, and then uses the others to find a user).

The field used to verify the password is `password`. You've already specified the `getAuthPassword` method in your user to make sure that it uses the `x_user_password` field. Laravel will thus check if the password credential entered can be hashed to the same value as in `x_user_password`.

As far as I can see this is the only mistake you made: not using the key `password` in your `Auth::attempt()` call.

If you have any issues with your session not sticking, ensure that the session cookie is properly sent to the server. Check your browser console under "Storage" and then "Cookies" to see if the cookie was sent to the browser. If the cookie isn't sent, the session will not be recognised, and you will not be logged in.

Sometimes the cookie will not be sent to the server, for example if you set `secure => true` in `session.php` (which can be done through `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true` in your .env). The cookie will then only be sent if you're visiting your app over HTTPS.

Other than the `secure` setting, the `domain` and `path` of course also matter. Since you've said you hadn't touched the `session.php` configuration I'll assume that there's no issues there.

Comment: This is wrong. In `auth::attempt()` it will check fields like `username` and `password`. Test it, before you answer

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I'm not sure where you found that. Of course I will not post an answer without testing it when I provide an answer. He's using the eloquent user provider, see `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider@retrieveByCredentials`. It allows you to use any key, so it's not required for it to be `username`. The only required one is `password` since it's hardcoded in `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider@validateCredentials`.